# Get a substring after an nth occurrence of a delimiter

Tags: regex, string, bash

There already is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559979/split-file-on-nth-occurrence-of-delimiter), but it refers to a file and I've got something more simple.

I need to get a sub-string after the nth occurrence of a delimiter (because the requirements for the occurrence are "flexible").

Let's say there is a string:

> s='HLGAPL65.HOU150.CHEVRONTEXACO.NET/UPSTREAM_MDM_D2/Jobs/Keystone Release 2.0.2.0/0.0. Loading_SOR_to_Landing/EGI/EGI_WV_WELLHDR.pjb'

The delimiter is:

> /

I need to get the substring after the 4th occurrence of the delimiter. SO that would be:

> 0.0. Loading_SOR_to_Landing/EGI/EGI_WV_WELLHDR.pjb

What would be the simplest one-liner to do that?

Comment: awk -F '/' '{print $5}' File

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cut` can make it:

```
$ cut -d'/' -f5- <<< "$s"
0.0. Loading_SOR_to_Landing/EGI/EGI_WV_WELLHDR.pjb
```

It sets the delimiter as `/` and prints from 5th field up to the end (`5-`).

Comment: the word 'beautiful' would fit the comments for such an answer

Answer (score 0):

Using BASH you can do:

```
s='HLGAPL65.HOU150.CHEVRONTEXACO.NET/UPSTREAM_MDM_D2/Jobs/Keystone Release 2.0.2.0/0.0. Loading_SOR_to_Landing/EGI/EGI_WV_WELLHDR.pjb'

[[ "$s" =~ ^([^/]*/){4}(.*) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
0.0. Loading_SOR_to_Landing/EGI/EGI_WV_WELLHDR.pjb
```