# Unix script for converting single line delimited to Multiline file

Tags: unix, awk

I have a file delimited with Cedilla, but the records are in a single line. I have to convert this to a multiline file.

Sample record:

```
P002365Ç1200ÇMastercardÇcarolinaÇBasildonÇEnglandÇUnited kingdomÇP002368Ç2100ÇVisaÇGouyaÇEchucaÇVictoriaÇAustraliaÇP002373Ç3600ÇMastercardÇRenee ElisabethÇTel AvivÇTel AvivÇIsraelÇP002382Ç6300ÇDinersÇbarbaraÇHyderabadÇAndhra PradeshÇIndia
```

Need to be converted to:

```
P002365Ç1200ÇMastercardÇcarolinaÇBasildonÇEnglandÇUnited Kingdom    
P002368Ç2100ÇVisaÇGouyaÇEchucaÇVictoriaÇAustralia    
P002373Ç3600ÇMastercardÇRenee ElisabethÇTel AvivÇTel AvivÇIsrael    
P002382Ç6300ÇDinersÇbarbaraÇHyderabadÇAndhra PradeshÇIndia
```

Can we achieve this using awk command?

Comment: Would this be what you are looking for?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559979/split-file-on-nth-occurrence-of-delimiter

HTHs

Comment: If you can use not only awk then this should work for you: perl -pe 's|Ç|\n|g' file.txt | paste -dÇ - - - - - - -

Answer (score 4):

You could use something like this:

```
awk -FÇ '{for (i=1;i<=NF;++i) printf "%s%s", $i, (i%7==0?RS:FS)}' file
P002365Ç1200ÇMastercardÇcarolinaÇBasildonÇEnglandÇUnited kingdom
P002368Ç2100ÇVisaÇGouyaÇEchucaÇVictoriaÇAustralia
P002373Ç3600ÇMastercardÇRenee ElisabethÇTel AvivÇTel AvivÇIsrael
P002382Ç6300ÇDinersÇbarbaraÇHyderabadÇAndhra PradeshÇIndia
```

A breakdown of what's going on here:

- `-FÇ` - This command line argument sets the `FS` variable (Field Separator) to the `Ç` character
- The for loop (executed on each line) loops from 1 to `NF` (Number [of] Fields)
- In each iteration, a `printf` is executed that prints two strings (`%s%s`), the first being the content of the actual field (`$i`) and the second being one of two options:

  1. If the Field Number is a multiple of 7*, a newline character is inserted (`RS` Record Separator),
  2. Otherwise the `FS` is printed. (Defined as the `Ç` character).

* The number 7 is used "arbitrarily" because it was your definition for splitting the records according to the example output you supplied.

Comment: `RS` (Record Separator) is the newline character in this case?

Comment: @Lix by default, yes it is.

Comment: As I suspected :P Cool.. I'm going to add a breakdown of what's going on here (mostly to make sure I understand it myself). Please let me know if I get something wrong :)

Comment: @Lix I just edited, hopefully that explains things a little more. Feel free to edit if you have any more detail to add.

Comment: Thanks, @tom. I've broken the explanation out into bullet points. Can you please confirm that I'm not misleading anyone or over simplifying :)

Comment: Looks good to me, I've removed my explanation as it was basically a less detailed version of yours!

Comment: Fantastic :) I should really follow the awk tag more... Really helps me to brush up on one of my favorite tools...

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/Ç/\n/7;P;D' file
```

This replaces every 7th `Ç` with a newline.