# Split file after number occurrence of delimiter

Tags: shell, awk

my question is essentially the same as answered in [split file on Nth occurrence of delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559979/split-file-on-nth-occurrence-of-delimiter) except that the solution will strip the delimiter before splitting. How would I split a fail after Nth occurrence of a delimiter while keeping all characters of the initial file? Example file:

```
aaa
bbb
$$$$
ccc
ddd
eee
$$$$
fff
ggg
hhhhh
$$$$
```

split after every 2nd occurrence of $$$$

```
awk '/^\$\$\$\$$/ { if(++delim % 2 == 0) { next } } { file = sprintf("chunk%s.txt", int(delim / 2)); print; END { print "ds" } }' < file
```

would delete the delimiter at the end of the chunk file

Comment: What's the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get it correctly and you want to split files on every 2nd occurrence of `$$$$` then try following.

```
awk -v file="1" -v occur="2" '
{
  print > (file".txt")
}
/^\$\$\$\$$/{
  count++
  if(count%occur==0){
    if(file){
      close(file".txt")
      ++file
    }
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: this worked for me great. thanks! quick followup: any good idea to make the output name increment a set of letters? aaaa, aaab, aaac like split?

Comment: @doom4, not clear, till when it should go? Could you please do add more details on same; it's always recommended to add expected output in your post itself.